# A grey square (overlay) in the middle of the screen, Ubuntu 16.04 Dell xps 13 9360

Tags: 16.04, dell, screen

I've this grey/black squarein the middle of my screen, when I change working spaces it follows.

[image: square in browser page] 
and here
[image: square over desktop]

Comment: A quick test to check if driver/graphic adapter issue or Software/Desktop one. Go Settings > Appearance > Behavior > Enable workspaces. Then press Super/Win+s. See if you have this square over all work spaces or it holds same position in the monitor? Take a screen shot and add it to the question.

Comment: From when this issue started.

Comment: Ok, I was simply stupid, overlay was caused by gnome-screenshot (selected only part of the screen and kept the window in background)

Comment: I've removed the 'solved' text from the question title; perhaps you can post your own answer explaining the solution and mark it correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, it was my fault.

The overlay was caused by gnome-screenshot still running in background after a screencap was made.

Problem is solved closing all istances of gnome-screenshot

Comment: This is actually a bug. I had the same problem Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Same thing,  thanks! Completely NOT off-topic. (btw, Dell Inspiron)

Comment: hahahaha ) I spent 30 min to figure out why by my own without googling

Comment: This is an ubuntu 16.04 bug. my system is completely different than anyone here. thanks for figuring it out though, was driving me nuts.